# how to style <xsl:value-of select="$somevalue"> element

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

i want to make the value from "xsl:value-of" attribute to to be bold. how i can achieve this? i tried using  which is not working. kindly guide me as i am new to xslt.

```
<fo:list-item-body >
    <fo:block>
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="$dosomething"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$doanotherthing"></xsl:value-of>
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fo:inline` (as shown without any additional properties specified on it) doesn't add anything.  Since `font-weight` is inherited, you can specify that on the `fo:block` and still not need the `fo:inline`:

```
<fo:list-item-body >
  <fo:block font-weight="bold">
    <xsl:value-of select="$dosomething"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$doanotherthing"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
```

However, if you're trying to make only part of your text **bold**, that's when you need another FO for the properties that will affect the formatting of just that text, usually either `fo:inline` (its own and inheritable properties) or `fo:wrapper` (for inherited properties of `fo:character` only):

```
<fo:list-item-body >
  <fo:block>
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:value-of select="$dosomething"/>
    </fo:inline>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$doanotherthing"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
```

(Note also that I'm showing the single-tag form for your empty `xsl:value-of` elements.)

Comment: thank you Tony. i wanted part of the text to be bold. your solution helped in solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `font-weight="bold"` attribute on your `fo:inline` element, e.g.

```
                <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$dosomething"></xsl:value-of>
                                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$doanotherthing"></xsl:value-of>
                            </fo:inline>
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#common-font-properties.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the styling attributes `font-weight` attribute should be used to obtain bold characters in output, like so:

```
<fo:list-item-body >
    <fo:block>
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="$dosomething"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$doanotherthing"></xsl:value-of>
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
```